# Voice over video with current sound

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation, software

I want to record a video and want to play some recorded voice over the video, but I still want the sounds of the original video to remain. Is this possible, and when the answer is yes, can you recommend the software you are doing this with?

Comment: Which platform (OS) do you using?

Comment: @Shultc I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in almost any video=editing software.

If you are using Windows and you do not have much experience in video editing, than you can make it Windows Movie Maker. It is free and simple for beginners.

Comment: Alright I will try it with the Movie Maker :)